# Split with regex, on first equal character on line

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string like this:

```
en.HelpPanel.Subtitle1=About
en.HelpPanel.SubText1a=Blah <a href="asdf">
```

I want to split by first `=` on the line. I want to get result of:

```
['en.HelpPanel.Subtitle1', 'About', 'en.HelpPanel.SubText1a', 'Blah <a href="asdf">']
```

However I am having trouble identifying just the first `=`. I tried this:

I am trying to define "equal character not preceded by another equal character", I tried this:

```
str.split(/^.*?=/)
```

But this gives:

```
Array [ "", "About\nen.HelpPanel.SubText1a=Blah <a href=\"asdf\">" ]
```

I tried multiline flag and it gave me this:

```
str.split(/^.*?=/m)


Array(3) [ "", "About\n", "Blah <a href=\"asdf\">" ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use regular expressions, you could use `match` instead of `split`:

```
str.match(/^.*?(?==)|[^=\n\r].*$/gm);
```

```js
const str = `en.HelpPanel.Subtitle1=About
en.HelpPanel.SubText1a=Blah <a href="asdf">`

const result = str.match(/^.*?(?==)|[^=\n\r].*$/gm);

console.log(result);
```

With `split`, you could do it like this:

```
str.split(/=(.*)[\r\n]*/gm);
```

The trick is that the regex capture group will also be returned in the output. But this `split` will return an extra empty string at the end, which you should then exclude.

```js
const str = `en.HelpPanel.Subtitle1=About
en.HelpPanel.SubText1a=Blah <a href="asdf">`

const result = str.split(/=(.*)[\r\n]*/gm);
result.pop(); // get rid of trailing empty string

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks this is a cool idea to get the solution to the problem! I was trying to learn the split regex thing though if possible please.

Comment: Added a solution based on `split`, but it requires an additional `pop`.

Comment: Thank you!! This is a very educational post for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex in `.match`:

```
/^([^=]*)=(.*)/gm
```

And grab text from captured group #1 and #2.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vPRohd/1)

**Code:**

```js
const regex = /^([^=]*)=(.*)/gm;
const str = `en.HelpPanel.Subtitle1=About
en.HelpPanel.SubText1a=Blah <a href="asdf">`;
let m;
let result = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) { 
    result.push(m[1], m[2]);  
}

console.log(result);
/*
[
  "en.HelpPanel.Subtitle1",
  "About",
  "en.HelpPanel.SubText1a",
  "Blah <a href=\"asdf\">"
]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `split` and `Array.flatMap` to achieve this.

Please note - `flatMap` is not supported by all browsers as of now (e.g. Edge)

```js
let str = `en.HelpPanel.Subtitle1=About 
en.HelpPanel.SubText1a=Blah <a href="asdf">`

console.log(str.split(/\n/).flatMap(d => ([a, ...b] = d.trim().split('='), [a, b.join('=')])))
```

Comment: Thanks but I was trying to just use regex one liner for learning. But +1

Answer (score 1):

You could [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on either a newline or an equals sign which is not followed by content between double quotes using a negative lookahead `(?!`:

`str.split(/=(?!"[^"]+")|\n`

```js
let str = `en.HelpPanel.Subtitle1=About
en.HelpPanel.SubText1a=Blah <a href="asdf">`;
console.log(str.split(/=(?!"[^"]+")|\n/));
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very educational post for me! I accepeted the other solution already but this is very informative thank you! +1